# if move from 12.04 to 14.04, will I have to reinstall mysql or apache?

Tags: release-management

I will use the "do-release-upgrade" command to move from 12.04 to 14.04. I would prefer not to get involved in having to upgrade or reinstall services. Will apache2 and mysql continue to run after the upgrade?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it will work and if the upgrade process can do its thing it'll all work out. If there is a power outage though you will run into trouble...

You can plan for upgrade failure. As with ALL upgrades:

I would assume you would dump your database and create a copy of my.cnf. That's all there if for MySQL. If it does not run after the upgrade it probably is a setting that needs tweaking.

Same for Apache: I would assume you create a backup of your settings (/etc/apache2/) and your websites (might be /var/www/) and other settings. Copying the old settings file over the new one generally works when I do this.